# Using MVC with Stash - nested model embeds for related entries (playa)

Tags: playa, stash

Using Stash 2.3.6, EE 2.5.5, Playa 4.3.3...

I want to stash a list of related playa entries for `Model1`. I want to assign the variables for `Model2` based on my `Model2` embed.

See `{!-- THIS IS NOT BEING SET --}` below:

If I manually assign variables with `{exp:stash:set}` within the playa loop, the code works fine. It is the nested embed that is failing.

Anyone have any advice for me? I love the way the code is laid out, and I want to keep it DRY.

**Main landing page (EE template)**

```
{stash:embed:layout:main}

{exp:stash:parse}
    {exp:channel:entries
        channel       = "list"
        limit         = "1"
        require_entry = "yes"
    }
        {if no_results}{redirect="404"}{/if}
        {stash:embed:model:model1 process="start"}
    {/exp:channel:entries}
{/exp:stash:parse}

{exp:stash:content}
    {exp:stash:get_list name="list_of_related_model2" process="end"}
        <li>{title} - {url_title}</li>
    {/exp:stash:get_list}
{/exp:stash:content}
```

**Model 1 (stash template)**

```
{exp:stash:set name="title"}{title}{/exp:stash:set}

{exp:stash:set_list name="list_of_related_model2" parse_tags="yes"}
    {exp:playa:children field="cf_related"}
        {stash:embed:model:model2 process="start"}{!-- THIS IS NOT BEING SET --}
    {/exp:playa:children}
{/exp:stash:set_list}
```

**Model 2 (stash template)**

```
{exp:stash:set name="title"}{title}{/exp:stash:set}
{exp:stash:set name="url_title"}{url_title}{/exp:stash:set}
```

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I'd suggest is that Model 2 should be a snippet. Capturing the standard entry fields (title, url_title, entry_id etc) is something I tend to do repeatedly in my viewModels, and I use a snippet called `{set_standard}` to do it so I don't repeat myself. The other issue here is that `process="start"` is relative to the processing of the root EE embed, NOT the immediate parent template of the embed (in Stash 2.3.6). As the embed is nested EE is already at the 'inline' phase of processing. Thus to get the above working would require including the embed in the root template (with output="no" so it doesn't display) and then referencing it as a placeholder `{stash:model2}` in the child template.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I will give it a try and post back how it works out